# How to see validation messages to API in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 8 and working on API's. I have created Request Classes for Form validation but when mobile developer hit API validation messages not displaying as required.
This is my controller method:

```
 public function store(InvoiceStoreRequest $request)
{
    try {
        return $this->responseWithSuccess(true,'Invoice Data',
               $this->invoiceInterface->store($request), Response::HTTP_OK);
    }catch (\Exception $exception){
        return $this->responseWithError($exception->getMessage(),Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
}
```

Here I am using `InvoiceStoreRequest` class to validate form.
Code for `InvoiceStoreRequest` is below:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'id' => ['required', 'string'],
        'invoice_date' => ['required', 'date'],
        'reference_number' => ['required'],
        'vendor_id' => ['required'],
        'invoice_net_total' => ['required','regex:/^\d*(\.\d{1,2})?$/'],
        'invoice_tax_total' => ['required', 'regex:/^\d*(\.\d{1,2})?$/'],
        'invoice_gross_total' => ['required', 'regex:/^\d*(\.\d{1,2})?$/'],
        'item_count' => ['required', 'numeric'],
        'invoice_type' => ['required','regex:(order|refund)'],
        'provider' => ['required'],
        'detail_url' => ['required'],
        'invoice_photo_url' => ['required'],
    ];
}
```

and for displaying custom messages,

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'invoice_type.regex' => 'The invoice type format is invalid. Invoice Type should be [order,refund]',
        'invoice_net_total.regex' => 'Invoice Net must be Decimal or Numeric value.',
        'invoice_tax_total.regex' => 'Invoice Tex must be Decimal or Numeric value.',
        'invoice_gross_total.regex' => 'Invoice Gross must be Decimal or Numeric value.',
    ];
}
```

It work fine on postman, but when Mobile developer hit API he get error with **422 Unprocessable Entity** but not showing error messages. I want to show error messages.
How can I solve this?

Comment: welcome to So ...  what response your getting in mobile ?

Comment: HTTP 422 is already the response ...the question is what is being posted (in particular the content-type). Therefore this question is not only a rough duplicate, but it also lacks relevant debugging information. The server-side code might not be wrongful at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Fix '422 Unprocessable Entity' when sending a POST request to Redmine API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56711503/how-to-fix-422-unprocessable-entity-when-sending-a-post-request-to-redmine-api)

Comment: #Kamlesh Request Failed with status code 422

Comment: Just tell that guy to set the proper content-type with his/her post... because I have issues to decide which of the 3 possible close-reasons I should apply. As it is, it is nothing that would be reproducible... and since postman works, the error is on his/her side, not yours (and I'm not trying to shift the blame here).

Comment: I added content type and still getting error

Comment: Error: Request failed with status code 422
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at EventTarget.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)
    at EventTarget.dispatchEvent (event-target-shim.js:818)
    at EventTarget.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:592)
    at EventTarget.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:395)
    at XMLHttpRequest.js:508
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:189)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:416)
    at MessageQueue.js:109

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make(request()->all(), [
    'name' => 'required',
    // ... Rules 
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return response()->json([
        'errors' => $validator->errors(),
        'status' => Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST,
    ], Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
}

MODEL::create($validator->validated());

return response()->json([
    'data' => [],
    'status' => Response::HTTP_CREATED,
], Response::HTTP_CREATED);
```

Answer (score 12):

You should add

```
Accept:application/json
```

to your request header when call api

for example:

[image]

Comment: I was stuck with this for a while. Thanks Bro.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're requesting JSON as response type:

```
 response = await fetch('{{ route('your.api.route') }}', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: formData,
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                    }
                });
```

Then to get Laravel's response do the following:

```
 const jsonResponse = await response.json();
```

Then you'll see the messages you're expecting in `jsonResponse`.